# Sum() is returning multiple values instead of summed value?

Tags: python, pandas

I am scraping a text file that has multiple data frames within it. I have a chunk of code the defines the start and end of each section (These lists are called Start & End).

```
#adding some code to create my error here
import pandas as pd
data = {'Begin': ['START', '', '', 'START', '', '', 'START', '', '','', 'START', '', ''],
'Type': ['Dog', '', 'END', 'Cat', '', 'END', 'Dog', '', '','END', 'Cat', '', 'END'],
    'breed': ['', 'Wolf', 'bork', '','Wolf', '', '','Wolf','bork','', '','Wolf','bork'],
    'Age': [20, 21, 19, 18,20, 21, 19,15,16,0, 19,15,16]
   }

data = pd.DataFrame(data)
Start = (data['Type'].index[data['Begin']=='START']).astype(int)

End = (data['Type'].index[data['Type']=='END']).astype(int)

for index, value in enumerate(Start):
    Frip = data.iloc[int(value) : End[int(f'{index}')]]
    #Caliente, pull in values and assign them
    if Frip.loc[value].str.contains('Dog').any() == True:
        #Frip = Main_DF.iloc[int(value) : End[int(f'{index}')]]
        #Frip.groupby(['YRMNTH'])
        TESTING = pd.to_numeric(Frip.query('breed == "Wolf"').Age)
        TESTING = sum(TESTING)
        print(TESTING)
```

##Anything below this point is from my previous post / code

```
#Here I am iterating through the list of values that have a starting index
for index, value in enumerate(Start):
    #Here I am splitting out the dataframe over each start and end value
    Frip = Main_DF.iloc[int(value) : End[int(f'{index}')]]
    #Here I am filtering to a specific value in the header and attempting to sum the values of each
    #chunk that also has this value in the header.
    if Frip.loc[value].str.contains('DOG').any() == True:
        TESTING = pd.to_numeric(Frip.query('Type == "Furry"').Header)
        TESTING = sum(TESTING)
        print(TESTING)
```

However, I am getting multiple values here instead of a summed value. I understand it has to do with it treating them seperately (sum does nothing) but how would I sum these values up?

I have tried messing with the result and creating a variable but I think I am making this too hard. I verified that the values are floats so they should be able to be summed.

Comment: MM2 - I may have mixed up the indentation in that second code block. Should the second for be outside of the first? Are these two different examples?

Comment: just provide us with an example of how the dataframe looks like. what you posted is of no help at all, especially that you seem very new to coding.

Comment: Not sure what is going on with the formatting but the indents are correct.

Comment: When I run this, I get this 5.0
47.0
34.0 I cannot share the dataframe due to how sensitive it is.

Comment: You do not need to share the dataset, Just simulate a fake dataset that describes your ideal problem and one will help you out.

Comment: Why `int(f'{index}')` instead of just `index`?

Comment: If you're getting multiple outputs, it simply means that the `if` condition is true for multiple values. Each `sum()` just returns one value, but you're doing it multiple times.

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve]. Chances are that you will find the error yourself that way. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Ok, I think I found a way to add an example to help demonstrate what I am getting.

Comment: @MM2 Great that you added the example. Can you also state what is the expected output for that example?

Comment: The expected output would be 36 (the two numbers summed together)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to sum the sums for each section like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Type': ['Dog', '', '', 'Cat', '', '', 'Dog', '', '','Cat'],
        'breed': ['', 'Wolf', 'bork', '','', '', '','Wolf','bork',''],
        'Age': [20, 21, 19, 18,20, 21, 19,15,16,0]
       }
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
Start = (data['Type'].index[data['Type']=='Dog']).astype(int)   
End = (data['Type'].index[data['Type']=='Cat']).astype(int)
total_sum = 0
for index, value in enumerate(Start):
    Frip = data.iloc[int(value) : End[index]]
    total_sum += pd.to_numeric(Frip.query('breed == "Wolf"').Age).sum()   
print(total_sum)
```

**Output**

```
36
```

Comment: I noticed you removed the IF condition. The IF condition is essential to what I am doing and I didn't do the best job in my example. There are going to be some instances where the CAT header has Breed == Wolf and I don't want those summed.

Comment: *"There are going to be some instances where the CAT header has Breed == Wolf*" But these rows are not included in the slice Frip, since frip is delimited by rows with Cat below. The row with Cat is not included in Frip, right?

Comment: I edited by example to show what I mean. If you remove that IF condition, it would count rows that have CAT as a header and Wolf as a Breed.

Comment: If I run with the updated data, the output is still 36 here..

Comment: Overall, this worked. I had the print indented so it was giving me all of the results but it seems to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with dataframes, you should use the dataframe.sum

It provides facility to use axis to make sum like row, column wise sum.

#### Check This out https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html

Comment: If I change  TESTING = sum(TESTING) to TESTING = TESTING.sum(), I get the same output.